# Mink + Behat - setting a value of radio to invalid value

Tags: php, behat, mink

I have a form where a user has to select a gender. This is a radio with two options - male and female. As a part of my test I want to see how the website reacts when something other than male or female is submitted. As the HTML of the page can easily be changed to anything on the user side, I want to imitate this behaviour in my scenario. However, browserKit that comes with Mink is too smart - it recognises it's dealing with a radio and helpfully throws me an exception if I try to change the value to something that is not expected.

> Input "application[sex]" cannot take "iDontKnow" as a value (possible values: male, female). (InvalidArgumentException)

```
  Scenario Outline: Submit form with various data
    Given I am on homepage
    And I fill in "application[name]" with "<name>"
    And I fill in "application[sex]" with "<sex>"
    And I fill in "application[age]" with "<age>"
    And I fill in "application[country]" with "<country>"
    And I press "Save"
    Then I should see "<expectedText>"

    Examples:
      | name      | sex       | age | country            | expectedText             |
      | Test user | iDontKnow | 30  | United Kingdom     | Invalid sex              |
      | Test user | male      | 30  | NonExistantCountry | Invalid country          |
```

How do I submit iDontKnow as a value to

```
<div id="application_sex">
   <input type="radio" id="application_sex_0" name="application[sex]" required="required" value="male">
   <label for="application_sex_0" class="required">male</label>
   <input type="radio" id="application_sex_1" name="application[sex]" required="required" value="female">
   <label for="application_sex_1" class="required">female</label>
</div>
```

... if it is even possible?

Looking at the ChoiceFormField::setValue gives a hint that some fundamentally different approach has to be taken.

It seems to be pretty usual case I am working with, so what is the recommended approach?

Comment: What I do is tricky, and I'm not sure I'd call it a "best practice": in development/test/staging, my template spits out an `<input type="text">`, which I can then fill out as I desire. In production, my template spits out `<select>`. I use a unit test to assert that. In your case, you'd basically change the input type depending upon whether you were in test or in production.

Comment: You could make them non required and have a result if they are not set,or have them both toggleable so both could be set [click - on click - off] and if both are set you could have a third result - they would need to be separate buttons rather than a pair for that though.  or you might add a third button with a "Prefer not to say" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As originally mentioned in my comment, I've handled this in the past by having my template system generate different markup to facilitate testing. In my scenario, the code looked approximately like this:

```
// templates/user-preferences.phpt
// ...
{% if $config->isTesting() %}
    {% include 'input-text.phpt' with options only %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'select.phpt' with options only %}
{% endif %}
```

I then have a unit test that sets the production configuration and ensures there's a select.

Having thought about this overnight, I've decided this isn't the right way to do it. Behat+Mink aims to test behaviors from a browser's perspective: whatever a conventional browser can do, you can do with Behat+Mink.

But this behavior - submitting values to a form that aren't in the form element - isn't part of what a conventional browser can do. You can't conventionally tell a browser to submit "baz" when the input element accepts only "foo" or "bar".

To send this data one has to, by definition, not use a browser. Therefore, Behat+Mink isn't the right tool for this job.

I think the proper way to test this case is to use a unit test to pump the out of bounds data into the accepting form on the server side. This might be your controller, or it might be a dedicated form class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been also thinking about this and it does seem like it may belong to unit testing other that behaviour testing. One can Inspect element in a browser though, and change the value of a select. But this is beyond a usual user. Problem here is that unit testing validation of forms in symfony is headache - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html says Don't test the validation: it is applied by a listener that is not active in the test case and it relies on validation configuration. Instead, unit test your custom constraints directly.

Comment: Right, I agree with Symfony: don't test your form view, test your form control. That "control" is often in a controller (think MVC) but sometimes it's in a form service. In short, you *should* unit test the code that performs the `if` to check the value is allowed.

Comment: That seems the way, but there is not simply an if statement in the code, instead it's annotations, yml files, form builder service, etc. It seems to tightly coupled to the symfony iteself. But the general direction is right - unit testing :-) Thanks a lot